# Values in a table, or spreadtab table, given to 2 decimal places

Tags: tables, spreadtab

I am developing a simple cash book on latex using spreadtab. How would I ensure that the Cost column always gives the value to 2 decimal places (it represents money). I would like the British format please of xx.xx (not xx,xx).

If possible, is there an equivalent of accounting format that could be used on excel, i.e a £ symbol to the left and the cost value on the right?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\title{Spreadsheet}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c}}
     @Date & @Date v.2 & @ Cost & @Fund & @Bank Acc & @Analysis \\
     \hline
     @01/01/2019 & 20190101 & 2.30   & @General & @HSBC &@Office Expenses   \\ 
     @02/01/2019 & 20190102 & 102.00 & @General & @HSBC &@ Rent\\
     @02/01/2019 & 20190102 & 32.00 & @General & @HSBC &@ Hospitality\\
     \hline
     & & sum(c2:c4) && \\
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of `siunitx` you can achieve the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{spreadtab}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\title{Spreadsheet}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{c|c|S[table-format=3.2, round-integer-to-decimal, round-mode = places, round-precision = 2]|c|c|c}}
     @Date & @Date v.2 & @ Cost & @Fund & @Bank Acc & @Analysis \\
     \hline
     @01/01/2019 & 20190101 & 2.30   & @General & @HSBC &@Office Expenses   \\ 
     @02/01/2019 & 20190102 & 102.00 & @General & @HSBC &@ Rent\\
     @02/01/2019 & 20190102 & 32.00 & @General & @HSBC &@ Hospitality\\
     \hline
     & & sum(c2:c4) && \\
\end{spreadtab}

\bigskip

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{c|c|S[table-format=3.2, round-integer-to-decimal, round-mode = places, round-precision = 2]|c|c|c}}
     @Date & @Date v.2 & {@ Cost in \pounds} & @Fund & @Bank Acc & @Analysis \\
     \hline
     @01/01/2019 & 20190101 & 2.30   & @General & @HSBC &@Office Expenses   \\ 
     @02/01/2019 & 20190102 & 102.00 & @General & @HSBC &@ Rent\\
     @02/01/2019 & 20190102 & 32.00 & @General & @HSBC &@ Hospitality\\
     \hline
     & & sum(c2:c4) && \\
\end{spreadtab}

\bigskip

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{c|c|>{\pounds}S[table-format=3.2, round-integer-to-decimal, round-mode = places, round-precision = 2, table-space-text-pre=\pounds]|c|c|c}}
     @Date & @Date v.2 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{@ Cost} & @Fund & @Bank Acc & @Analysis \\
     \hline
     @01/01/2019 & 20190101 & 2.30   & @General & @HSBC &@Office Expenses   \\ 
     @02/01/2019 & 20190102 & 102.00 & @General & @HSBC &@ Rent\\
     @02/01/2019 & 20190102 & 32.00 & @General & @HSBC &@ Hospitality\\
     \hline
     & & sum(c2:c4) && \\
\end{spreadtab}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the author of spreadtab seems to preferably use `numprint`, here is a solution wih the `N` column type. For the number of decimal digits, you have the command `\STautoround*{2}`. For the `£` currency unit, I suggest using it in the column head once and for all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell, numprint}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{numprint}
 \npdecimalsign{.}
\title{Spreadsheet}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\STautoround*{2}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{c|c|N{3}{2}|c|c|c}}
     @Date & @Date v.2 &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\makecell{@ Cost\\ (£)}}& @Fund & @Bank Acc & @Analysis \\
     \hline
     @01/01/2019 & 20190101 & 2.301 & @General & @HSBC &@Office Expenses \\
     @02/01/2019 & 20190102 & 102.997 & @General & @HSBC &@ Rent\\
     @02/01/2019 & 20190102 & 31.998 & @General & @HSBC &@ Hospitality\\
     \hline
     & & sum(c2:c4) && \\
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

[image]